# How do I add an uppercase asterisk in MS Word formula editor

Tags: microsoft-word

A couple of formulas I made in the MS Word formula editor

> [image]

However, the last **(*)** should be exactly that: an asterisk, not a multiplication sign. I want it be higher - it's there for a note that says that in certain conditions the last term (ОФО) is not used in the formula.

The formula editor automatically turns * into a multiplication sign - how do I avoid that in this particular case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force Word to interpret * as a character - not a mathematical symbol.
Write: "*" with quotes

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I should not that this does not work right away - I entered the first quote, then the asterisk, then the second quote - and still the asterisk was in the form of a multiplication symbol. Then I pressed the space button, and voila! The quote marks vanished, and there was my asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's the cleanest solution, but u can make asterisk as upper index of the left bracket. `(^*` and then just write the right bracket.