# How to force MS Word 2007 formula editor to interpret the word "recovery" not as "re COV ery"?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm translating this simple formula for recovery, and MS Word's formula builder interprets the **cov** as some separate word ("covariate"?), while I want the whole word "recovery" to be in italic:

> [image]

I tried placing quote marks around the word: "recovery" - but that fails to work. It worked [some time ago with another issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1172856/how-do-i-add-an-uppercase-asterisk-in-ms-word-formula-editor), but not here.

Comment: have a look in math autocomplete, maybe you can remove "cov" from there.

Comment: `cov` is `covariance`, if you were interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. When in the formula editing mode, one should select "Style" in the upper menu and choose "text". Voila!

Here it is - "Style" is "Стиль" in Russian:

> [image]